# Write an efficient function that has a large case expression with lots of function calls

Tags: sql, sql-server

My function takes too long to run. I want to:
A. Find out exactly why it is taking so long
B. Optimize the function or execution plan.

The function: NOTE:  Several separate functions are called in each 'THEN' clause.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [History].[getPrimaryID_Asset_Asset](@table varchar(32), @schema varchar(32), @column_name varchar(max), @column_value varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ID varchar(max) = @schema + '.' + @table + '.' + @column_name 
    IF SUBSTRING(@Schema, 1, 1) != '[' SET @Schema = QUOTENAME(@Schema)
    IF SUBSTRING(@Schema, 1, 1) != '[' SET @Table = QUOTENAME(@Table)
    RETURN
    
    CASE 
    WHEN @column_value IS NULL THEN NULL
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].AssetTypeAutoID' THEN  [Enum].getAssetType(CONVERT(int, @column_value)) 
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].AssetStatusAutoID' THEN [Enum].getAssetStatus(CONVERT(int, @column_value)) 
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].ModelNumberAutoID' THEN [ModelNumber].getModelNumberID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].ProjectAutoID' THEN [Project].getProjectName(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].CabinetAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].SystemAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].PowerSupplyAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].PlantModelAutoID' THEN [Location].getPlantModelID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].ColumnAutoID' THEN [Location].getColumnID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].DeviceTypeAutoID' THEN [Typical].getDeviceTypeID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].RackAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].PLCAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].CalBoxAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].GasTypeAutoID' THEN [Enum].getGasType(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].RedundantAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].VertexAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].PRMAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].NACAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].ConduitAssetAutoID' THEN [Asset].getAssetID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].GasZoneTypeAutoID' THEN [Enum].getGasZoneType(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    WHEN   @ID = '[Asset].[Asset].ProcurementPlantModelAutoID' THEN [Location].getPlantModelID(Convert(int, @Column_Value))
    ELSE  @column_value
    END
END
```

I tried looking at the execution plan to see what steps were taking so long. Originally, I was running this function within an update trigger that was updating 600+ rows of a table called Asset.Asset.  It was taking about 55 seconds to run. I pulled the execution plan for a simple use of my function from
`select History.getPrimaryID_Asset_Asset('Asset','Asset', 'ProcurementPlantModelAutoID', '1000')`
to illustrate where my problem is.

When I look at the Execution Plan, I see A clustered index seek for every function that is in a 'THEN' statement.  Even the ones that should never get used.
I cannot seem to include the full execution plan details on here so I will show 2 screen shots illustrating what I mean.
[ExecutionPlanStart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGwnL.png)

[ExecutionPlanBranches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0BuT.png)

I do not fully understand what I am looking at, but it appears that the trailing branches in the execution plan all are related to the functions used in THEN statement and each of them take time.
Is there a way to optimize my function to take less time or avoid the execution plans evaluation of functions in 'THEN' statements that are not used?

Comment: Convert your functions to table valued functions... they typically perform much better than scalar functions.

Comment: this kinda of function will unlikely to perform great no matter what you do. why not just do a join to get the data you need?

Comment: There is a lot of code smell in here. If your "column_value" is always converted to an int why are you passing it in as a varchar? You also seem to have a bug in your code. Look at your second set of replace at the top. You check schema twice, the second one should be check table. But no matter how you slice this thing up those nested scalar functions are going to be dreadful. The execution plan needs to be different for those different paths but your code has rendered that impossible. As a result you will get the cached plan which will not always be good for performance.

Comment: You also seem to be passing in a schema, table and column name using varchar(32). Those should be sysname as the datatype which is an alias for nvarchar(128). Your datatype may work now but it will likely break at some point when you have longer names.

Comment: Probably best to just use a separate function for every query type, rather than trying to bodge it into one.

Comment: If you are using either SQL Server 2019 or the upper version, the Scalar-valued function inlining may help you.

Comment: Parameterise the name of the @function and execute @function: `declare @function nvarchar(500) = CASE @ID 
WHEN '[Asset].[Asset].AssetTypeAutoID' THEN  '[Enum].getAssetType'
WHEN '[Asset].[Asset].AssetStatusAutoID' THEN '[Enum].getAssetStatus'
WHEN '[Asset].[Asset].ModelNumberAutoID' THEN '[ModelNumber].getModelNumberID'
WHEN '[Asset].[Asset].ProcurementPlantModelAutoID' THEN '[Location].getPlantModelID';

if try_cast(@column_value as int) is not null and @function is not null
begin
  exec @column_value=@function @column_value;
end
return(@column_value);`

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple [IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) **statements** instead of single complex [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  **expression**, to run exactly one simple query for each function invocation.